# XSL to HTML: Issues with contains method

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a really strange situation. In my case contains works with one value and doesn't work with another. I've tried debugging for XSLT (not much help here).

The situation is following. I have a following XML structure:

```
<RejRow>
 <Column>
    <ColumnName>GRP</ColumnName>
    <ColumnValue>1234w5</ColumnValue>
    <ValidationType>GRP: Non-Integer Value</ValidationType>
  </Column>
  <ColumnName>TCL</ColumnName>
    <ColumnValue>lklk3343//</ColumnValue>
    <ValidationType>TCL: Non-Alphanumeric Value</ValidationType>
  </Column>
 </RejRow>
```

And I have two **for-each** calls, for one it does work, for other it does not... Tried to look into everything and still no clue why it does not work for me. If works for Non-Alphanumeric.

This one does not work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="RejRow[contains(Column/ValidationType, 'Non-Integer Value')]">
<tr>
    <td>test1</td> 
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

And this one does:

```
<xsl:for-each select="RejRow[contains(Column/ValidationType, 'Non-Alphanumeric Value')]">
<tr>
    <td>test1</td> 
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Interestingly if I explicitly specify the whole validation name, for-each does work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="RejRow[Column/ValidationType='GRP: Non-Integer Value')]">
<tr>
    <td>test1</td> 
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed; it's missing a `<Column>` start tag. This often suggests that the XML shown is not what you were actually running against; for example you might have made other changes you considered insignificant, like omitting namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `RejRow[Column[contains(ValidationType, 'Non-Integer Value')]]` or `RejRow[Column/ValidationType[contains(., 'Non-Integer Value')]]` instead of `RejRow[contains(Column/ValidationType, 'Non-Integer Value')]`. As you have several `Column` elements your `contains` in XSLT 1 will use the first `Column` one while in XSLT 2 or 3 you would get an error.

Comment: Thanks so much! It seems to be working. Could you be more detailed, why did it work for Non-Alpha then? This was just a dummy example, in real code I have many rows, many columns and many ValidationTypes. So the goal of my foreach is to find all columns matching a specific validation (not necessarily the only one, there could be several ValidationTypes as well). Will it also work if I have several ValidationTypes in the list, not only the matching one?

Comment: The second suggestion starting with `RejRow[Column/ValidationType[...]]` should do to check there is at least one `Column` with at least one `ValidationType` that satisfies the `...` check.

Comment: As for your "working" case, it is hard to tell with that snippet that is not well-formed, but as I tried to explain, the use of `contains(Column/ValidationType` in XPath/XSLT 1 will select the first `Column/ValidationType` in document order and perform the check on it, so I suppose if that "worked" against some input then only because the first `Column/ValidationType` satisfied the condition.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `contains(NN, value)` and NN is a node-set containing more than one node, then (a) in XPath 1.0, all nodes in NN other than the first are ignored, and (b) in XPath 2.0, it throws an error. `Column/ValidationType` is a node-set containing 2 nodes, so it looks as if you're using XPath/XSLT 1.0. It was changed in 2.0 because so many people fall into this trap: yet another reason to move forward (or persuade your software vendor to do so).